# Problem Using Wall Anchors for Curtain Rod

Tags: windows, screws, drill, hanging, drywall-anchor

I'm trying to hang curtains for a floor-to-ceiling window by using drywall anchors to hold up the curtain rod. However, the plastic screw gets stuck about halfway anywhere I attempt to drill. When I attempt to push the plastic screw further in while drilling, it just expands the hole outward rather than becoming flush with the wall. How can I do this correctly so as to install the curtain rod?

Comment: If they're only going halfway in then there must be something behind the drywall--either a stud, lathe, or brick/cement.

Comment: You may be able to run the screw right into the framing with out using the anchors. It will hold much better if it is framing and not wood lath or masonry. if the bracket are directly over the window, you may have found the header.

Comment: @Jack - Thanks. This is exactly as one of my friends suggested and it worked perfectly. If you entered that as an answer rather than I comment, I'd choose it as the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to run the screw right into the framing with out using the anchors. It will hold much better if it is framing and not wood lath or masonry. if the brackets are directly over the window, you may have found the header.